# How to query on Node property?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

```
create (s:Student {name:'Jack'}), 
(t:Teacher {name: 'Mary', age: '30'}), 
(s)-[r:has_teacher]->(t)
```

How to make this Cypher query question:

Find Jack's teacher's name and the answer should be 'Mary'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the requirements in the comments, you can ignore patterns that the teacher's name is `null`:

```
MATCH (s:Student)-[r:has_teacher]->(t:Teacher)
where s.name = "Jack" and t.name is not null
return t.name;
```

In some cases you may want query only by patterns that `:Teacher` nodes have the `name` property:

```
MATCH (s:Student)-[r:has_teacher]->(t:Teacher)
where s.name = "Jack" and EXISTS(t.name)
return t.name;
```

Comment: Thanks, Bruno.  That's great.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
MATCH (s:Student)-[r:has_teacher]->(t:Teacher) where s.name = "Jack" return t.name;
```

Comment: I changed my question a little bit. Please see again. Sorry about the mistake.

Comment: Its simple. Please check the edit. Also, you can refer to cypher query documentation for more details and learning : https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/

Comment: Let me know if there is any issue with the query.

Comment: If some teachers don't have the 'name' attribute (assuming that in my model). How to avoid the t.name to return null value?

Comment: Then what should it return in case there is no name property?

Comment: Don't return. Just return values when they are not null.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164714/discussion-between-binariedme-and-user697911).